# Engine not functioning properly at idle (cold or hot), during driving, slow acceleration, does not increase speed

Tags: engine, vw, sparkplugs, acceleration, polo

I have a VW POLO (6N2) - 1.4 (60Hk), from February 2000.

After the car was standing still for 2 days in a rural area close to a stream (damp environment), the car had issues with being idling. Even after the car was heated. This issue did not exist before.  After a 20 minute drive, and 10 minutes of the car being turned off, when I start the car it works fine at idle.

In addition, it has a hard time increasing speed. When I accelerate normally the car sort of jumps and the speed is not increased.

I am bit unsure of what can cause these issues, searching around on the Internet has led me to:

- Issues with water/condensation in the fuel/fuel-lines?
- Issue with the power distributor for the spark plugs?
- The wires from the power distributor to the spark plugs?
- The spark plugs?
- The air intake or air leak ?

I find it a bit strange and would like some pointers on where to start with troubleshooting the issue.   :)

**Solution**

I did not locate the specific issue, but I purchased new `spark plugs` and `Ignition coil` and it ran smoothly again :)
So do this if you ever have the issue!

Comment: Could you provide the year of your vehicle please?

Comment: @DucatiKiller just added it, it is from February 2000, when it was bought new.

Comment: When the car is warmed up and idling, if you step on the gas to rev the engine do the rev's hang for a bit and then suddenly drop down to a rough or normal idle?

Comment: @DucatiKiller no, then it sounds and looks as normal.

Comment: So this issue only occurs when the car is cold?  Is the issue consistent and happens every time the car has completely cooled down?

Comment: @DucatiKiller The last 2 weeks yes. But the acceleration issue persists after the motor is fully heated.

Comment: @DucatiKiller today after work (car standing in damp and cold environment), the car had no troubles in any of the above cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32683/discussion-between-ducatikiller-and-jtim).

Comment: Is everything still behaving normally?

Comment: @DucatiKiller Had One day where the car had small issue in idle, but after a few minutes it was fine. I'm inclined to think that I should change the spark plugs and cables, as I cannot guess other issues?

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: @DucatiKiller the issue is not there anymore at least, but I am not confident that it is gone. But do not know how to find the issue, when it isn't persistent.

Comment: Yes, that certainly adds a layer of painful difficulty on top of everything.  Well, I would be interested in hearing about the solution if/when you find it.   Please jam it up in here if you discover the root of it.  Best of luck to you!